# Python pickle syntax

Tags: python, io, pickle

I'm using the latest python release and after searching, I can't seem to find anything on pickles that will work for me.

I am simply going through tutorials attempting to learn about pickling and none of the source code that apparently works on the tutorials will work for me, I suspect this is something to do with the tutorials being outdated.

What I have tried and is the same as what tutorials show is:

```
import pickle 
lists = [1,2,3,4,5]
pickle.dump(lists, open('log.txt', 'a+'))
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
pickle.dump(lists, open('log.txt', 'a+'))
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

this

```
>>> import pickle
>>> unpicklefile = open('log.txt', 'r')
>>> unpickledlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> unpickledlist = pickle.load(unpicklefile)
```

gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
unpickledlist = pickle.load(unpicklefile)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Thank you for any replies and help

Comment: Your code works fine for me with no errors (except for matching the filenames used). So, **what error did you actually get**?

Comment: It sounds like you're following a tutorial designed for Python 2.x, while you seem to actually be using Python 3.x. There are subtle differences, and if you want to use Python 3.x then it would be best to follow a tutorial designed for that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'a+'` mode may be causing you problems.  And, if you're on Windows, it would be useful to open a file in a binary mode.  Also, you should close the file before reopening to read it back in.  And make sure you're writing and reading the same file ('log.txt' vs. 'filename'):

```
import pickle 
lists = [1,2,3,4,5]

f = open('tmp_pickle.pic', 'wb')
pickle.dump(lists, f)
f.close()

f = open('tmp_pickle.pic', 'rb')
unpickledlist = pickle.load(f)
print unpickledlist
```

Comment: This seems to work for me so you are probably right about the problem being because I am using 'a+'. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: This answer solves the problem because opening a file with a `'b'` mode (in Python 3.x) expects `bytes` from the writer instead of `str` (which is an unencoded Unicode string). The `pickle` module expects to be able to write `bytes`, see [the `pickle.dump` documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) for details ("The *file* argument must have a write() method that accepts a single bytes argument.")